# How much does a cup of Nutella weigh?

Tags: conversion, recipe-scaling, measuring-scales

I want to make Nutella cookies. I've found a recipe for it, but it's in volume measurements. It asks for a cup of Nutella and I don't own a cup.

I tried searching my regular converters, but the only one with a hit was Wolfram-Alpha and I've noticed this result can be quite wrong.

Is anybody kind enough to weigh a cup of Nutella? Or do you use a converter that knows the weight of a cup of Nutella?

Note: I do own a tablespoon measure, so if nobody knows, I'll just scoop out some and calculate it myself. And post it as an answer of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I actually measured and weighed a cup of Nutella and I got 290g. Of course we have to take into consideration my 1 cup measurement (I'm pretty sure they are not exactly the same) and my scale. But it just shows that the 300g mark is not far off.

Answer (score 16):

According to the nutella nutritional fact label, 1 tbsp = 19g.

There are 16 tbsp in a cup so 16 * 19g = 304g

[image]

Comment: I doubt its going to matter in this case, but you've got some inaccuracies there. First, 19g is presumably 19±0.5g, so you could be off by up to 8g from that. Second, 1T on a nutrition label is a tiny bit bigger than 1T in a recipe (yes, not only does the US have weird measuring units, we have two sets of them under identical names! See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cup_%28unit%29 for details)

Comment: @derobert, thanks, I did not know that. So "1 cup" in a recipe, is the customary cup I assume? But I agree that it won't matter for my cookies.

Comment: @Mien: 1 cup in the recipe is probably the customary cup. Or, really, the size of the measuring cup the recipe author used. Calibration of measuring cups is often very loose.

Answer (score 6):

On my Nutella jar it says that 2 tablespoons of the deliciousness is 37 grams. So, 37x8= 296 grams of Nutella is one cup.

Comment: What's with the downvote? The larger the initial measurement, the less error propagation you get, so this answer is probably closer to accurate than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my trick for measuring sticky, dense things like Nutella: Take whatever liquid you're using and measure an amount, like 1 cup.  add the Nutella to the liquid and the level will rise to the measurement you need.  For example, if I need 1/2 cup of Nutella and there is milk in my recipe, I'll put 1 cup of milk on my measuring cup, add enough Nutella to bring the combined volume to 1.5 cups.  Makes cleaning easier too.

Comment: Hi Big Crank. Did you actually read the question? How is the OP supposed to put anything in a measuring cup if he ***doesn't own a measuring cup***?

Comment: Although this was not helpful for me particularly, I can imagine it is useful for some people. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @Marti because a measuring cup's worth of thin liquid can easily be measured with either fluid measuring cup (which most kitchens have if they don't have dry measuring cups), or by using a scale and weighing off 250 grams. BTW, one more that needs to go in the "international cooking terms" question...

Answer (score 5):

I estimated that 1 cup of nutella is around 294 grams:

I bought a jar of 350 grams of nutella, used a marker to indicate the nutella level of the jar. Emptied it (I was gonna use it for cookies anyway adjusting the recipe to just one 1 jar).

After cleaning the jar out. I put it on a scale and filled with water. In went 282 grams of water = 282 milliliter of water = 1.19 cups of water.

The 350 grams of Nutella in the jar was 1.19 cups -> Ergo: 1 cup of Nutella = 350/1.19 = 294 grams.

Note 1: The = sign should be interpreted as "equals about" 
Note 2: Who would write a recipe needing a cup of nutella, it is almost impossible to measure it.

Comment: @Daniel G: your 1.2 g/mL is correct, since 350ml=294 gram (350/294=1.24)

Answer (score 1):

Nutella is a bit specialised for most online converters, but butter is virtually the same density, and a cup of that weighs 238g. I wouldn't think you'd go far wrong with that.

Comment: I like http://www.onlineconversion.com/weight_volume_cooking.htm if you find the product density online, it can be entered to give exact results

Answer (score 1):

In my research I found my answer to my question.  A 13 oz jar of Nutella is equivalent to 1.6 cups for persons that use volume measurements.  I used 1 cup 6 oz. Hope this helps somebody:) Fredsmom

Answer (score 0):

The density of Nutella is 1.2g/ml.
Therefore 300grams is equal to 250ml.

Comment: Where did you find the density? Or did you measure it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

The recipe I saw asking for Nutella cookies measured by cup specified 'using dry measuring cup rather than the one used for liquids'. I live in (non-UK) Europe where we routinely do everything by grams and deciliters subsituting weight for volume and the normal substitution would be around 235-250 ml more or less depending on weight per volume